# Double Consonant in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, for-loop, boolean

I made a function `double consonant()`. Here it's all well. But when I try to change little the logic with symbol `!==` in second function `double_consonant_2()` my program work wrong and i'm confused.

i want to say that each element from `sentence` which is not equal with vowel. i mean equal with consonant. Double the words and between them add the letter `o`.

```js
// double consonant with consonant variable.
function double_consonant(sentence) {
  var result = "";
  var consonant = "qwrtypsdfghjklzxcvbnm";
  for (var i = 0; i < sentence.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < consonant.length; j++) {
      if (sentence[i] === consonant[j]) {
        result += sentence[i] + "o" + sentence[i];
      }
    }
  }

  return result;
}

console.log(double_consonant("good"));


// dobule consonant with vowel variable.
function dobule_consonant_2(sentence) {
  var result = "";
  var vowel = "aeouiAEOUI";
  for (var i = 0; i < sentence.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < vowel.length; j++) {
      if (sentence[i] !== vowel[j]) {
        result += sentence[i] + "o" + sentence[i];
      }
    }
  }

  return result;
}

console.log(dobule_consonant_2("here"));
```

Comment: Why not use indexOf instead of === or indexOf ===-1 instead of !==

Comment: Your logic in the second function is wrong. If a letter isn't `a` it might be a different vowel, so you can't use that to check if it's a consonant.

Comment: I want to learn how to think logically in order to better understand how things work. That's why i don't use indexOf method.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your second function is that your `if` filters each vowels independently.
In your example with `here`, when reaching the `e`, the second loop will check if the letter is different from `a`, which is true, and so add the `o` between, and then continue to check the other vowels.

What you could do is check for all the vowels and then decide :

```
var isVowel = false;
for (var j = 0; j < vowel.length; j++) {
  if (sentence[i] === vowel[j]) {
    isVowel = true;
    break;
  }
}
if(!isVowel) {
    result += sentence[i] + "o" + sentence[i];
}
```

Note that it's not the fastest way, using indexOf in the first method seems easier.

Comment: Thank you so much. Now I am analyzing my mistakes.